# Boggle using Trie and DFS

Tags: c#, programming-challenge, trie

I already mentioned in my previous code review, there are two solutions for this problem
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/boggle-find-possible-words-board-characters/

this is the first:
[Find all possible words in a board of characters](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/223165/boggle-find-all-possible-words-in-a-board-of-characters-c)

and here comes the second.

Original question is:

> Given a dictionary, a method to do a lookup in the dictionary and a M
>   x N board where every cell has one character. Find all possible words
>   that can be formed by a sequence of adjacent characters. Note that we
>   can move to any of 8 adjacent characters, but a word should not have
>   multiple instances of the same cell.
>
> ```
> Example:
>
> Input: dictionary[] = {"GEEKS", "FOR", "QUIZ", "GO"};
>        boggle[][]   = {{'G','I','Z'},
>                        {'U','E','K'},
>                        {'Q','S','E'}};
>       isWord(str): returns true if str is present in dictionary
>                    else false.
>
> Output:  Following words of the dictionary are present
>          GEEKS
>          QUIZ
> ```

Please review for performance and any other comments,
thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace TrieQuestions
{
    [TestClass]
    public class BoggleTrie
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void BoggleTrieTest()
        {
            string[] dictionary = { "GEEKS", "FOR", "QUIZ", "GEE" };
            char[,] boggle = {{'G','I','Z'},
                              {'U','E','K'},
                              {'Q','S','E'}
            };

            Trie tree = new Trie();
            foreach (var word in dictionary)
            {
                tree.Insert(word);
            }

            FindWords(boggle, tree);
        }

        private void FindWords(char[,] boggle, Trie root)
        {
            int M = boggle.GetLength(0);
            int N = boggle.GetLength(1);
            bool[,] visited = new bool[M,N];
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                {
                    //all the words start with one of the letters in the head of the Trie
                    if (root.Head.Edges.ContainsKey(boggle[i, j]))
                    {
                        str.Append(boggle[i, j]);
                        SearchWord(root.Head.Edges[boggle[i,j]], boggle, i, j, visited, str);
                    }
                    str.Clear();
                }
            }
        }

        private void SearchWord(TrieNode child, char[,] boggle, int i, int j, bool[,] visited, StringBuilder str)
        {
            if (child.IsTerminal)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(str.ToString());
            }

            int M = boggle.GetLength(0);
            int N = boggle.GetLength(1);

            if (IsSafe(M, N, i, j, visited))
            {
                visited[i, j] = true;

                foreach (var edge in child.Edges)
                {
                    for (int row = i - 1; row <= i + 1; row++)
                    {
                        for (int col = j - 1; col <= j + 1; col++)
                        {
                            if (IsSafe(M, N, row, col, visited) && boggle[row,col] == edge.Key)
                            {
                                SearchWord(edge.Value, boggle, row, col, visited, str.Append(edge.Key));
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }

                visited[i, j] = false;
            }
        }

        private bool IsSafe(int M, int N, int i, int j, bool[,] visited)
        {
            return i < M && i >= 0 && j < N && j >= 0 && !visited[i, j];
        }
    }
}
```

NO NEED TO REVIEW THE TRIE code

here only for reference

```
public class Trie
{
    public TrieNode Head { get; set; }

    /** Initialize your data structure here. */
    public Trie()
    {
        Head = new TrieNode();
    }

    /** Inserts a word into the trie. */
    public void Insert(string word)
    {
        var current = Head;
        for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!current.Edges.ContainsKey(word[i]))
            {
                current.Edges.Add(word[i], new TrieNode());
            }
            current = current.Edges[word[i]];
        }
        current.IsTerminal = true;
    }

    /** Returns if the word is in the trie. */
    public bool Search(string word)
    {
        var current = Head;
        for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!current.Edges.ContainsKey(word[i]))
            {
                return false;
            }
            current = current.Edges[word[i]];
        }
        return current.IsTerminal == true;
    }

    /** Returns if there is any word in the trie that starts with the given prefix. */
    public bool StartsWith(string prefix)
    {
        var current = Head;
        for (int i = 0; i < prefix.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!current.Edges.ContainsKey(prefix[i]))
            {
                return false;
            }
            current = current.Edges[prefix[i]];
        }
        return true;
    }
}

public class TrieNode
{
    public Dictionary<char, TrieNode> Edges { get; set; }
    public bool IsTerminal { get; set; }
    public TrieNode()
    {
        Edges = new Dictionary<char, TrieNode>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When testing you solution with the following dictionary:

```
      string[] dictionary = { "GEEKS", "GEEKSQ", "SEEK", "EGIZK", "EEK", "FOR", "QUIZ", "GO" };
```

I get this result:

```
GEEKS
GEEKSQ
EGIZK
EGIZKEK
QUIZ
SEEK
SEEKEEK
EEK
```

The reason must be that you don't reset the `str` object after each recursive call to `SearchWord`:

> ```
> if (IsSafe(M, N, row, col, visited) && boggle[row,col] == edge.Key)
> {
>   SearchWord(edge.Value, boggle, row, col, visited, str.Append(edge.Key));
> }
> ```

You must remove the previous `char` before the next `boggle[row, col]` is tested in the recursive call.

```
   if (IsSafe(M, N, row, col, visited) && boggle[row,col] == edge.Key)
   {
     SearchWord(edge.Value, boggle, row, col, visited, str.Append(edge.Key));
     str.Length--;
   }
```

---

> ```
>   if (IsSafe(M, N, i, j, visited))
>   {
>     visited[i, j] = true;
> ```

I see no reason for this check, because you know that it's safe from the previous recursion:

> ```
> if (IsSafe(M, N, row, col, visited) && boggle[row,col] == edge.Key)
> {
>     SearchWord(edge.Value, boggle, row, col, visited, str.Append(edge.Key));
> ```

---

> ```
>     if (IsSafe(M, N, i, j, visited))
>     {
>         visited[i, j] = true;
>
>         foreach (var edge in child.Edges)
>         {
>             for (int row = i - 1; row <= i + 1; row++)
>             {
>                 for (int col = j - 1; col <= j + 1; col++)
>                 {
>                     if (IsSafe(M, N, row, col, visited) && boggle[row,col] == edge.Key)
>                     {
>                         SearchWord(edge.Value, boggle, row, col, visited, str.Append(edge.Key));
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>
>         }
>
>         visited[i, j] = false;
>     }
> ```

I think there is a possibility for optimization here: Instead of iterating all the edges on the current node it is only necessary to test those where `boggle[row, col]` is safe:

```
  // if (IsSafe(M, N, i, j, visited))
  {
    visited[i, j] = true;

    //foreach (var edge in child.Edges)
    {
      for (int row = i - 1; row <= i + 1; row++)
      {
        for (int col = j - 1; col <= j + 1; col++)
        {
          if (IsSafe(M, N, row, col, visited))
          {
            char key = boggle[row, col];
            if (child.Edges.TryGetValue(key, out TrieNode edge))
            {
              SearchWord(edge, boggle, row, col, visited, str.Append(key));
              str.Length--;
            }
          }
        }

      }
    }

    visited[i, j] = false;
  }
```

---

So a gentle rewriting of `SearchWord` - eliminating the need for `IsSafe()` could be:

```
private void SearchWord(TrieNode child, char[,] boggle, int i, int j, bool[,] visited, StringBuilder str)
{
  if (child.IsTerminal)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(str.ToString());
  }

  int M = boggle.GetLength(0);
  int N = boggle.GetLength(1);

  int minRow = Math.Max(0, i - 1);
  int maxRow = Math.Min(M, i + 2);
  int minCol = Math.Max(0, j - 1);
  int maxCol = Math.Min(N, j + 2);

  visited[i, j] = true;

  for (int row = minRow; row < maxRow; row++)
  {
    for (int col = minCol; col < maxCol; col++)
    {
      if (visited[row, col])
        continue;

      char key = boggle[row, col];
      if (child.Edges.TryGetValue(key, out TrieNode edge))
      {
        SearchWord(edge, boggle, row, col, visited, str.Append(key));
        str.Length--;
      }
    }
  }

  visited[i, j] = false;
}
```

---

Besides that I have the usual "complaints" about naming, mixing test and implementation, not repeating yourself, the benefits of creating a proper class as with the other version - and it's of course sloppy just to write the result to the console, instead of returning it.

---

In order to make it more C#-style you could rewrite it, so the api looks like:

```
public IEnumerable<string> FindWords(char[,] boggle, Trie root)
```

and:

```
private IEnumerable<string> SearchWord(TrieNode child, char[,] boggle, int i, int j, bool[,] visited, StringBuilder str)
```

and then use `yield return str.ToString()` when ever a word is found.

Comment: I noticed you use indentations of 2 spaces. The default is 4 on CR, if I'm not mistaken. You find this to have improved readability?

Comment: 2 spaces does stimulate the use of nested 'for if do while do do if '.. blocks :-p

Comment: As always amazing review. I wasn't sure about the return value I guess you are right.

Comment: It does add readability for such cases. The question is whether such cases should be rewritten in their entirety :) But this is out of scope of this OP/Answer. I will stop polluting your comments :p