# Union, Intersection and Diff of two sorted arrays in C#

Tags: c#, programming-challenge, array

This is the original question
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/union-and-intersection-of-two-sorted-arrays-2/

> Given two sorted arrays, find their union and intersection.
>
> ```
> Example:
>
> Input : arr1[] = {1, 3, 4, 5, 7}
>         arr2[] = {2, 3, 5, 6}  
> Output : Union : {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7} 
>          Intersection : {3, 5}
>
> Input : arr1[] = {2, 5, 6}
>         arr2[] = {4, 6, 8, 10}  
> Output : Union : {2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10} 
>          Intersection : {6}
> ```

I also added one more case of finding items which are only in one of the two arrays and called it *Diff*.

Please review for performance. 
**Please do not comment** about code in the same class as the test and the functions not being static. It is just faster for me like this to get to the point of the exercise.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace ArrayQuestions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/union-and-intersection-of-two-sorted-arrays-2/
    /// </summary>

    [TestClass]
    public class UnionAndIntersectionOfTwoSortedArrays2
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void UnionTest()
        {
            int[] arr1 = { 1, 3, 4, 5, 7 };
            int[] arr2 = { 2, 3, 5, 6 };
            int[] union = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
            CollectionAssert.AreEqual(union, Union(arr1, arr2));
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void IntersectionTest()
        {
            int[] arr1 = { 1, 3, 4, 5, 7 };
            int[] arr2 = { 2, 3, 5, 6 };

            int[] intersection = { 3, 5 };
            CollectionAssert.AreEqual(intersection, Intersection(arr1, arr2));
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void DiffTest()
        {
            int[] arr1 = { 1, 3, 4, 5, 7 };
            int[] arr2 = { 2, 3, 5, 6 };

            int[] diff = { 1, 2, 4, 6, 7 };
            CollectionAssert.AreEqual(diff, Diff(arr1, arr2));
        }

        private int[] Diff(int[] arr1, int[] arr2)
        {
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
            int n = arr1.Length;
            int m = arr2.Length;
            List<int> list = new List<int>();
            while (i < n && j < m)
            {
                if (arr1[i] == arr2[j])
                {
                    i++;
                    j++;
                }

                else if (arr1[i] < arr2[j])
                {
                    list.Add(arr1[i]);
                    i++;
                }
                else
                {
                    list.Add(arr2[j]);
                    j++;

                }
            }

            while (i < n)
            {
                list.Add(arr1[i]);
                i++;
            }
            while (j < m)
            {
                list.Add(arr2[j]);
                j++;
            }
            return list.ToArray();
        }


        private int[] Intersection(int[] arr1, int[] arr2)
        {
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
            int n = arr1.Length;
            int m = arr2.Length;
            List<int> list = new List<int>();
            while (i < n && j < m)
            {
                if (arr1[i] == arr2[j])
                {
                    list.Add(arr1[i]);
                    i++;
                    j++;
                }
                else if (arr1[i] < arr2[j])
                {
                    i++;
                }
                else
                {
                    j++;
                }
            }

            return list.ToArray();
        }

        public int[] Union(int[] arr1, int[] arr2)
        {
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
            int n = arr1.Length;
            int m = arr2.Length;
            List<int> list = new List<int>();
            while (i < n && j < m)
            {
                if (arr1[i] < arr2[j])
                {
                    list.Add(arr1[i]);
                    i++;
                }
                else if (arr2[j] < arr1[i])
                {
                    list.Add(arr2[j]);
                    j++;
                }
                else // equals
                {
                    list.Add(arr1[i]);
                    i++;
                    j++;

                }
            }
            //handle the rest
            for (; i < n; i++)
            {
                list.Add(arr1[i]);
            }
            for (; j < m; j++)
            {
                list.Add(arr2[j]);
            }

            return list.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _It is just faster for me like this to get to the point of the exercise._ If you code really fast, would you also expect a fast review?

Comment: @dfhwze I mean to say that please disregard why it is not separate class for test and for the rest of the code.

Comment: I get what you mean, but still it would be a very small effort to extract the algorithm to a separate class and call that class in the unit tests.

Comment: @dfhwze I started doing it. because for some reason you find it very annoying.. and I appreciate the code reviews.

Comment: It looks like both `Union()` and `Intersection()` are the basic implementation of the algorithms which do not handle duplicates (`Union`  of {  1, 2, 2, 2, 3  } and { 2, 3, 4, 5 }) gives {1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5} not {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} and `Intersection` of { 2,5,5,6,6} and {4,6,6,8,10} gives {6,6} not {6}) is this intended?

Comment: @AlanT, I am not sure, but I will do one with duplicates, thanks for noticing

Comment: I see you are practicing various algorithms but writing working code is a _no-brainer_. Doing it in a way that can be maintained, tested and easily understood, with intuitive API is much much harder and on higher levels this is what counts most. Currently you just write _something_ to solve the task avoiding to implement additional types to encapsulate the logic in proper modules. If you want to improve your skills you should try to write more professional code with proper types, names etc. I would still classify this code as _beginner_.

Comment: @t3chbot thanks for the comment. I have been working for Intel for more than 7 years as a software developer. What you say is absolutely correct. But that has almost no meaning in jobs interviews. So I practice both. At Intel of course my peer code review and design review everything with me. Stuff like S. O. L. I. D principles and design patterns and maintable well written code is a must.

Comment: Now forget everything and take 3 questions put a clock to 45 minutes and solve.

Comment: I have noticed that Google, Amazon, Microsoft, Facebook and Apple and many other companies have very high demands on job interviews. I am trying to get to that level of solving and written good code for those interviews. I already got job offers from some of them and failed some of them. So I keep practicing. I think we do not use stuff like max heap and Trie trees on our day to day job.

Comment: @t3chb0t I also try to tackle more complex interview questions like so https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/223218/boggle-using-trie-and-dfs/223249#223249

Comment: If one of your primary goals is to write working code within 45 minutes without paying attention to any coventions or clean-code _rules_, or in other words simply quick-n-dirty, then IMO you only have one question: _Can this code be improved in terms of language features?_ or _Can this code be technically done better?_ - anything else would go beyond what you are trying to achieve here. I think this is your only question in this _series_, am I right?

Comment: @t3chbot I am not sure there is right or wrong here. Some of the code reviews gave me wonderful insights of things I was not even aware of. Some technical and some sruff like you are looking at the problem from a wrong point of view. I think it is very hard to pin point what can be done in 45 minutes. All the reviews you and many others give me definitely raise the bar. Remember the goal for me is to get better in any type of coding. So please continue to review I learn from each review.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You can optimize all 3 methods if you initialize `list`'s capacity to the longest of the two arrays. Resizing a list involves allocating a new internal array and copying old items into the new array, which is something to keep in mind if you care about performance.
- Your tests often contain small pieces of manually crafted data. That's not a very scalable approach. It's easy to generate large amounts of test data with a bit of Linq: `Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).Select(i => random.Next(0, 1000)).OrderBy(n => n).ToArray()` gives you an input array. Verification can be done with a few loops (is every number in `arr1` and `arr2` present in `union`, and is every number in `union` present in either `arr1` or `arr2`?). For the duplicate-handling implementation verification is even easier with a combination of Linq's `Union`, `Intersect` and `OrderBy` methods.
- Names like `i`, `j`, `n` and `m` are not very descriptive - specifically which array they're associated with is not clear from their names. Changing them to something like `index1`, `index2`, `length1` and `length2` will make that relationship clear.
- If you're storing array lengths in local variables, then why not also store the results of `arr1[i]` and `arr2[j]` in local variables before comparing them? Both of these are micro-optimizations that affect the readability of the code, so I would only do this for performance-sensitive code, and only when profiling shows that it's actually an improvement.

Comment: Regarding the first and last points, the attempts at optimising could well go wrong if it messes with the CLR. It used to be the case, for example, and cycling forward through an array was faster than backward because the optimiser would remove redundant bound checks: any additional indirection (e.g. stuffing lengths in variables) might break this. As you say: only do it if you know it is a problem and it shows an improvement upon (realistic) measurement.

Comment: Would you allow names as i1, i2, n1, n2 or prefer the longer names as mentioned in your answer?

Comment: @dfhwze: personally I find the longer variant a bit easier to read so that's how I would write it, but in both cases the relationship with `arr1` is clear, so I'd be fine with either.